# Using JSX with traceur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, traceur

I am using browserify with es6ify (that uses traceur). I am using React and I have jsx files.
I pass the `{ jsx: true }` option to es6ify, but I keep getting exception whenever browserify sees jsx file. Using babel works.

Is there another thing I have to do in order to enable jsx with traceur?

I tried to use reactify before es6ify, but it complains on es6 syntax like `import` and `export`.